# Как добавить несколько цветов (разукрасить) текст в легенде Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Мне нужно разукрасить разными цветами легенду в своём графике на `Chart.js`.
Пытаюсь подсунуть цвет прямо в текст, но выводит напрямую с кодом цвета.

Моя задача текст "по данным открытых источников" сделать разноцветным. Например, слово "данным" сделать красным цветом, а "источников" сделать зелёным. Возможно ли провернуть такое ? З

```html
const ctx = document.getElementById('chart');

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Россия', 'Канада', 'США', 'Китай', 'Бразилия'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'площадь в млн. кв. км.',
        data: [17.125, 9.985, 9.834, 9.599, 8.516],
        borderWidth: 2,
        // https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/colors.html#per-dataset-color-settings
        borderColor: 'rgba(245, 40, 40, 0.8)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(245, 40, 40, 0.5)'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Статистика государств',
        // https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html
        font: {
          family: 'monospace',
          size: 14
        }
      },
      subtitle: {
        display: true,
        text: 'по данным открытых источников',
        font: {
          family: 'monospace',
          size: 12
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Возможно ли провернуть такое ?

Comment: Черезе span не сработало

Comment: Показывает код цвета как текст. Так зачем вы тогда в тему зашли, если не имеете желания разбираться ?

Comment: MEXANIZM100 добро пожаловать на сайт => (Заходят в "тему" вопрос все, кто его видят на главной странице и кто онлайн в данный момент, заходят, думают могут ответить/помочь, видят ваш вопрос, не ясно к чему subtitle применяется и либо нет времени сразу ответить , либо не знают что ответить) Если кому будет именно знаком отрезок кода, он ответит обязательно(что достаточно снижает процент отвечающих), а вам я предлагаю посмотреть ссылку на "правила" вопросов, чтоб понимать за что минус (не мой если что) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Спасибо. Приму к сведению. В вопрос должны заходить программисты знающие библиотеку chart.js, иначе нет смысла. Поэтому subtitle указано без описания откуда и зачем. Сам вопрос подразумевает определённый уровень знаний для помощи другим.

Comment: если вы считаете, что в вопрос "должны" заходить только те, кто знающие, можете на мете об этом предложить https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZJGE.png https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/ 

Comment: Вы не поняли сути изложенного мною. Я считал так и считаю, поэтоу и теги указывавются, что бы проще отыскать подобные темы и подсказать разбирающимся в этом людям, что именно в этой теме, допустим, требуются знания в тако-то области.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно с чем конкретно у Вас возникли проблемы, т.к. Вы не привели рабочий пример используемого Вами кода. Помимо этого в [официальной документации](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest) имеются исчерпывающие примеры.

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('chart');

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Россия', 'Канада', 'США', 'Китай', 'Бразилия'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'площадь в млн. кв. км.',
        data: [17.125, 9.985, 9.834, 9.599, 8.516],
        borderWidth: 2,
        // https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/colors.html#per-dataset-color-settings
        borderColor: 'rgba(245, 40, 40, 0.8)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(245, 40, 40, 0.5)'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Статистика государств',
        // https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html
        font: {
          family: 'monospace',
          size: 14
        }
      },
      subtitle: {
        display: true,
        text: 'по данным открытых источников',
        font: {
          family: 'monospace',
          size: 12
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div>
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Из вашего примера моя задача текст "по данным открытых источников" сделать разноцветным. Например, слово "данным" сделать красным цветом, а "источников" сделать зелёным. Возможно ли провернуть такое ? Заранее спасибо

Comment: @MEXANIZM100 скопируйте код в свой вопрос и поясните это там, т.к. не все дойдут до этого комментария, либо обратят на него внимание. Я же не нашёл способа использовать HTML непосредственно в свойстве text.